# Deletion of legacy locked off-topic question on SO

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, vote-to-delete, locked

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685779/most-annoying-colleague-behavior-and-how-to-deal-with-it) that was most likely forgotten.

Could a mod delete it? Or am I being too picky?

Comment: It may be old and locked, but it's still cruft.  +1.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't remember why I locked that instead of deleting it.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: And now that the question has been deleted should we delete this question?  Or should we wait until someone asks in a new question?

Comment: I used this opportunity to cast my very first meta close vote.

Answer (score 1):

I flagged it as requiring Mod attention; it's locked so voting to delete is out of the question. Only a diamond bearer can help us now. Paging Dr. Yeuh....

Comment: Thanks for the flag.  That's usually a bit faster, since I check those when I'm bored and meta when I'm *just a little bit more* bored.