# An interesting test case for delete vote numbers

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012373/recursion-adding-numbers/6012538#6012538.

It appears that the vast number of upvotes on a humorous answer push up the delete threshold on this vastly downvoted question.

Is this really quite the intended effect?

Comment: That question is number one on Proggit at the moment, so it's a pretty pathological example :)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50967/question-deletions-are-getting-out-of-hand and the follow-up http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51097/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2010 for some thoughts on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Preserving an incredibly good (and thus, highly upvoted) answer in spite of a terrible question (highly downvoted) question, that *is* an intention of the system. The reason it is based on both question and answer votes was because of an initial concern users had that excellent answers were being destroyed thanks to awful questions that they happened to be posted on (the turning point being a couple Eric Lippert answers).

So in that vein, something that's so terribly voted down, that has an answer which is so vastly upvoted, that's *technically* an intended effect that it is more difficult to destroy.

In this *specific* case, though, it's more of an anomaly because the votes here are an anomaly. As noted by [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) in a comment, it's a Proggit link, which explains why the votes are much higher than the answer may truly be useful for.

Comment: It's isn't an 'incredibly good' answer. It's an 'incredibly witty' answer, at the expense of the OP. Which is perilously close to 'being a jerk' if you ask me.

Comment: "Preserving an incredibly good (and thus, highly upvoted) answer in spite of a terrible question (highly downvoted) question, that *is* an intention of the system." -- In theory, perhaps. In practice, almost all questions which spawn Reversal badges are deleted in short order.

Comment: @Rosinante I did mention this was an anomaly.

Comment: @Gra point taken.

Comment: @mmyers I originally figured that, but I don't know how it currently is. But at the time the system was introduced, there were apparently enough *good* reversals that it was a problem.

Comment: @mmyers A side effect of that is that the Reversal badge is difficult to get once, and almost impossible to get twice :)

Comment: @Wether: In fact, only one user has it twice. And he got them both on the same day, both on very old questions, and... hmm... uh oh.